# OutOfBoundsException failed when getAttrTypeAt

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I got the below exception from DB, when running some query over a DB using JDBC.
Can you advise what can cause that slide out of the array as it looks like from the below ?

Perhaps is it possible to view OracleTypeADT.java source code ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.getAttrTypeAt(OracleTypeADT.java:3082)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.pickle81rec(OracleTypeADT.java:2079)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.pickle81(OracleTypeADT.java:1958)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeUPT.pickle81(OracleTypeUPT.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCOLLECTION.pickle81(OracleTypeCOLLECTION.java:318)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.pickle81(OracleTypeADT.java:1937)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.linearize(OracleTypeADT.java:1540)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.toBytes(ArrayDescriptor.java:730)
    at oracle.sql.ARRAY.toBytes(ARRAY.java:812)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setArrayCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:6455)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setARRAYInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:6412)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setArray(OraclePreparedStatement.java:6355)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setArray(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:121)
```

Comment: Does the array have the same number of indexes as arguments expected by the PreparedStatement?

Comment: Can you post you'r PreparedStatement, with mock data?